# AngularJS parameters in Url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, javascriptservices

I am using AngularJS and I want to create one service that consumes a REST API.

The service definition is like

```
function DiscoveryService($resource, userContextService) {
    var apiBaseUrl = userContextService.getApiBaseUrl();
    return $resource(apiBaseUrl + '/ports/:transferId/discovery/:messageId',
        null, {
            update: {
                method: 'PUT'
            },
            get: {
                method: 'GET'
            },
            remove: {
                method: 'DELETE'
            }
        });
}
DiscoveryService.$inject = ['$resource', 'userContextService'];
module.exports = DiscoveryService;
```

the problem is that in some pages the `:transferId` and `:messageId` work, Url is being built properly (e.g. `ports/12323435/discovery/2`).

In some other pages don't work. Url is `/ports/discovery` without the ids. I track it in Fiddler.

Could anyone please explain how the `:trasnferId` works? or link to a relating webpage?

thanks for any help

Comment: Can you show us two examples of how you are using the service that result in what you see in Fiddler?

Comment: These are the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Comment: thanks for the link